How can I make an automatic login with a user via a script?
I have created a GPO within a domain that runs a computer startup script (when the computer is turned on, it runs that script). What this script does is to create a scheduled task that restarts the computer every day at 23:00.
Here is the script code (it is a PowerShell script):
# We define the time we want the computer to restart
$triggerTime = "23:00" # 24 hours format HH:MM
       
# We create a new trigger that will be executed daily at the specified time
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $triggerTime
    
    
# We define the action we want the task to perform, in this case, restarting the computer
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "shutdown.exe" -Argument "/r"
    
    
# Specifies the options for running the task whether the user is logged in or not
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -LogonType S4U -RunLevel Highest
    
    
# We create the scheduled task with the specified options
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Reinici" -Trigger $trigger -Action $action -Principal $principal -Description "Reinicia l'ordinador cada dia a les 23:00" -Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable)

All this works perfectly, on the computers that I assign the GPO, when I restart them to apply the policies, the task is created, and they restart at 23:00, and if they already have the task created it also works, but I need that on those computers, they log in automatically with a specific user, I think it can also be done from a PowerShell script that runs when the PC starts. If you need more information to know more, don't hesitate to ask, I might have left out some basic things to know.
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

You cannot login remotely with a User and Password because the password is not encrypted.   You have to create a credential where the password is encrypted. You want to create a credential  and impersonate another user.  See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/run-powershell-with-different-credentials-without-prompt-on/m-p/2660927

@jdweng they are using the System account. What password are you talking about? @ OP a computer startup script will work on any computer, regardless of what users log in or not.

@DougMaurer : They are using a System Account because it is automatically run at startup?  Only if the task used the default and not using "Run As".  You really want to run as a Service account and not System.  The OP says "they log in automatically with a specific user" which is not System.  This implies impersonation.  if you are logging remotely a Credential must be used especially if you are trying to impersonate.

I think you want to run the script with a service account (probably with Admin Privilege).  When script is started you want to use "Run As" when script is started.  You also want to create a Service Account on the Machine with Admin privilege.

No if you actually look at the code  you will see $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "SYSTEM" -LogonType S4U -RunLevel Highest which is the scheduled task being set to run as the SYSTEM account. Computer startup scripts don't run as users. What are you even talking about??
